# Boxplot not showing range

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science, logistic-regression, boxplot

I have predicted values, via:

```r
glm0 <- glm(use ~ as.factor(decision), data = decision_use, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

predicted_glm <- predict(glm0, newdata = decision_use, type = "response", interval = "confidence", se = TRUE)

predict <- predicted_glm$fit
predict <- predict + 1

head(predict)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.3715847 0.3095335 0.3095335 0.3095335 0.3095335 0.5000000
```

Now when I plot a box plot using ggplot2,

```r
ggplot(decision_use, aes(x = decision, y = predict)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(decision)), alpha = .2)
```

I get a box plot with one horizontal line per categorical variable. If you look at the predict data, it's same for each categorical variable, so makes sense.

But I want a box plot with the range. How can I get that? When I use "use" instead of predict, I get boxes stretching from end to end (1 to 0). So I suppose that's not it. Thank you in advance.

To clarify, predicted_glm includes se.fit values. I wonder how to incorporate those.

Comment: I think you just want `type = "response"` if you're looking for numbers in the 0-1 range (i.e predicted probabilities) rather than log odds, which is what `type = "link"` will return for a logistic regression. The log odds can be anywhere from -Inf to +Inf

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you. I did that, and now the values seem much more like what I had expected. Thank you for this. But I still don't get a range in box plot..... would you know how I can get it?

Comment: @AllanCameron or any other plot that'd be appropriate. All my independent variables are categorical variables. "use" is 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to do a boxplot here. A boxplot shows the range and spread of a continuous variable within groups. Your dependent variable is binary, so the values are all 0 or 1. Since you are plotting *predictions* for each group, your plot would have just a single point representing the expected value (i.e. the probability) for each group.

The closest you can come is probably to plot the prediction with 95% confidence bars around it.

You haven't provided any sample data, so I'll make some up here:

```r
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(outcome = rbinom(200, 1, c(0.1, 0.9)), var1 = rep(c("A", "B"), 100))
```

Now we'll create our model and get the prediction for each level of my predictor variable using the `newdata` parameter of `predict`. I'm going to specify `type = "link"` because I want the log odds, and I'm also going to specify `se.fit = TRUE` so I can get the standard error of these predictions:

```r
mod <- glm(outcome ~ var1, data = df, family = binomial)
prediction <- predict(mod, list(var1 = c("A", "B")), se.fit = TRUE, type = "link")
```

Now I can work out the 95% confidence intervals for my predictions:

```r
prediction$lower <- prediction$fit - prediction$se.fit * 1.96
prediction$upper <- prediction$fit + prediction$se.fit * 1.96
```

Finally, I transform the fit and confidence intervals from log odds into probabilities:

```r
prediction <- lapply(prediction, function(logodds) exp(logodds)/(1 + exp(logodds)))

plotdf <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "B"), fit = prediction$fit,
                     upper = prediction$upper, lower = prediction$lower)
plotdf
#>   Group  fit     upper      lower
#> 1     A 0.13 0.2111260 0.07700412
#> 2     B 0.92 0.9594884 0.84811360
```

Now I am ready to plot. I will use `geom_point`s for the probability estimates and `geom_errorbar`s for the confidence intervals :

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plotdf, aes(x = Group, y = fit, colour = Group)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), size = 2, width = 0.5) +
  geom_point(size = 3, colour = "black") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  labs(title = "Probability estimate with 95% CI", y = "Probability")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is actually what I ended up going with a couple of days ago. Thank you -- I will mark it an answer still.